# How to solve amd_gpio AMDI0030:00 INVALID CONFIG PARAM 0014?

Tags: boot, bluetooth

New Ubuntu user here. Installed Ubuntu on my new Lenovo Ideapad 1 laptop. Here’s a minor problem. The boot screen displays the following errors:

1. amd_gpio AMDI0030:00 INVALID CONFIG PARAM 0014
2. Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read codec capabilities (-22)

Here is what I tried to solve it :

1. GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off".
2. sudo apt update and upgrade
3. GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet loglevel=3 splash"

I couldnt solve it. Is there a chance for a newbie to solve this annoying messages?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet loglevel=3 splash"

This is the right solution, you add `loglevel=3` into that line in `/etc/default grub` but you have to run

```
sudo update-grub
```

afterwards and you shouldn't get those errors. It simply means don't log errors with a severity of warning or below.

I don't know about the bluetooth one, but the AMD one is an unimportant error that can happen in normal circumstances AMD have submitted a patch to resolve it in later kernels simply by downgrading the log severity from error to debug so it won't be shown. You can simply do nothing and the error will disappear as you get a newer kernel at some point.

If bluetooth is working fine for you then that's also not a problem. These are just drivers thinking out loud as they initialise rather than the system logging meaningful errors.